# Which logger framework in java shall one use based on performance and consistency criterion?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

Which logger framework in java shall one use based on performance and consistency criterion?
I need to use it in highly concurrent application and do not wish to use any log wrappers.

Please suggest based on these requirements.

-Vaibhav

Comment: What do you mean by "consistency"?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/index.html) - intended as a successor to the popular log4j project. It's fast, generic and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Check SL4J - Simple Logging Facade for Java

http://www.slf4j.org

It's very easy to implement and (from its page)

```
SLF4J serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks
```

It then can be used then with lockback, log4j, etc..